# indexof doesn't change until the variable is empty or a specified value even though it should check on every keyup event

Tags: javascript, indexof, keyup

I can't update my compatibilityIndex boolean value on every keyup, because the value of indexof on which it depends updates itself only when one of the search values is emptied or has specified value, like "rice" or "red wine". Does anyone know, why is it happening even though it should check it on every keyup event?

```
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="big col-xs-12">Prepare your dinner according to the reference of mixing rules to attain the optimum harmony of taste.</h1>
</div>
    <hr />
    <h2 class="searchQ">Main ingredient</h2>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient1" class="search search1" value="">
    <hr />
    <h2 class="searchQ">Complementary ingredient</h2>
    <input type="text" name="ingredient2" class="search search2" value="">
    <hr />
    <h1>You <span class="can">can</span> mix <span class="searchVal1"></span> <span class="and"></span> <span class="searchVal2"></span> with:</h1>
    <ul class="list1"></ul>
    <ul class="list2"></ul>
    <script>
        var redWine = ['Red Wine','Cheese','Cured Meats','Red Meat'];
        var rice = ['Rice','White Wine','Chicken'];
        var whiteWine = ['White Wine','Chicken','Oyster','Rice'];

        var notFound = "Nope, don't think you can eat that";

        var search = $('.search');
        var search1 = $('.search1');
        var search2 = $('.search2');
        var search1conv = [];
        var search2conv = [];
        var compatibilityIndex = false;
        var can = $('.can');
        var searchVal1 = $('.searchVal1');
        var and = $('.and');
        var searchVal2 = $('.searchVal2');
        var list1 = $('.list1');
        var list2 = $('.list2');

        function checking(checkedVal, searchConv, list) {
            switch ( checkedVal.toLowerCase() ) {
                case 'red wine':
                case 'wine red':
                case 'wine, red':
                    list.empty();
                    searchConv = redWine;
                    for (var i = 1; i < redWine.length; i++) {
                        list.append('<li>' + redWine[i] + '</li>');
                    }
                    break;
                case 'rice':
                    list.empty();
                    searchConv = rice;
                    for (var i = 1; i < rice.length; i++) {
                        list.append('<li>' + rice[i] + '</li>');
                    }
                    break;
                case 'white wine':
                case 'wine white':
                case 'wine, white':
                    list.empty();
                    searchConv = whiteWine;
                    for (var i = 1; i < whiteWine.length; i++) {
                        list.append('<li>' + whiteWine[i] + '</li>');
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    list.empty().append('<h2>' + notFound + '</h2>');
                    break;
            }
        }
        var compatible = function(ing1, ing2) {
            if ( ing1.indexOf(ing2[0]) > -1 && ing2.indexOf(ing1[0]) > -1 ) {
                compatibilityIndex = true;
            } else {
                compatibilityIndex = false;
            }
        }

        var main = function() {
            search.keyup(function() {
                if (search1.val() != 0 || search2.val() != 0) {
                    if (search1.val() != 0) {
                        checking( search1.val() , search1conv , list1 );
                    } else {
                        list1.empty();
                    }
                    if (search2.val() != 0) {
                        checking( search2.val() , search2conv , list2 );
                    } else {
                        list2.empty();
                    }
                } else {
                    searchVal1.empty();
                    searchVal2.empty();
                    list1.empty();
                    list2.empty();
                }
                if (search1.val() != 0 && search2.val() != 0) {
                    compatible(search1conv, search2conv);
                    if (compatibilityIndex) {
                        can.text('can').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
                    } else {
                        can.text('can\'t').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
                    }
                    searchVal1.text( search1.val() );
                    and.text('and' + " " + search1conv.indexOf(search2conv[0]) + " " + search2conv.indexOf(search1conv[0]));
                    searchVal2.text( search2.val() );
                } else {
                    if (search1.val() == 0) {
                        can.text('can').removeClass('red').removeClass('green');
                        searchVal1.empty();
                        and.empty();
                    } else {
                        searchVal1.text( search1.val() );
                    }
                    if (search2.val() == 0) {
                        can.text('can').removeClass('red').removeClass('green');
                        searchVal2.empty();
                        and.empty();
                    } else {
                        searchVal2.text( search2.val() );
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(main);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me apologize in that this isn't an answer to your question, but as I started to go through your code, I see tremendous amounts of redundancy in variables and functions. This makes your code more complex and more difficult to debug. I would start by simplifying the code. For example, you don't need a checking1 and checking2 function - they both do the same thing, they just operate on different data. By passing more data to the function, you can have one function for both sets of data:

```
function checking(checkedVal, searchConv, list) {
    switch ( checkedVal.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'red wine':
        case 'wine red':
        case 'wine, red':
            list.empty();
            searchConv = redWine;
            for (var i = 1; i < redWine.length; i++) {
                list.append('<li>' + redWine[i] + '</li>');
            }
            break;
        case 'rice':
            list.empty();
            searchConv = rice;
            for (var i = 1; i < rice.length; i++) {
                list.append('<li>' + rice[i] + '</li>');
            }
            break;
        case 'white wine':
        case 'wine white':
        case 'wine, white':
            list.empty();
            searchConv = whiteWine;
            for (var i = 1; i < whiteWine.length; i++) {
                list.append('<li>' + whiteWine[i] + '</li>');
            }
            break;
        default:
            list.empty().append('<h2>' + notFound + '</h2>');
            break;
    }
}
```

I see lots of other examples of redundancy in your code. Again, my apologies - I know you didn't ask for this advice, but I believe that it will help you in the long run to find any problems you are encountering.

Comment: No worries. I need to get rid of those unnecessary lines anyway. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Eh, I changed it to the one You provided, so it's unified, however now the "compatible" function ALWAYS show -1, which is weird. I'll work on it.